# Calling repeat control from csjs?

Tags: xpages

I have this bit if code that I am successfully calling from ssjs

```
 "vwEquipmentActiveByCategorySubcategoryBriefDescription/"+rowData.getUniversalID() +"/$FILE/"+rowData.getColumnValues()[4]
```

Now I need to call it from csjs.  How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you need something like a download link? If so, place a xp:link control and compute the href property to above url.

Comment: I am dynamically creating a URL for an image in SSJS.   I am using a repeat control to create this URL.  What I want to do now is calculate that same URL but in CSJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was to use a click event SSJS to take the image URL (computed from the repeat control) and store it in a CSS hidden field.   My CSJS then references that field.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

there is an XSP object in client side, it allows you to do few callback to server.

So try to use this

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet(refreshId, options) or XSP.partialRefreshPost(refreshId, options)
```

Triggers a partial refresh manually. For POST the refreshId must point to a form, for get it can be any element with a partial refresh defines. The options object is quite interesting to examine. Includes parameters and functions to execute in the life cycle.

So simply put ID of your repeat control and XSP.partialRefreshGet or Post and check if it works. and for sure it will work if u put your control in panel and pass ID of your panel to refresh method.